# Accepted answer not listed on top

Tags: support, questions, answers, self-answer

I was just browsing the question [Deserializing empty xml attribute value into nullable int property using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295697/deserializing-empty-xml-attribute-value-into-nullable-int-property-using-xmlseri?answertab=votes#tab-top) on stackoverflow and I noticed that the accepted answer is listed after the answer with the highest votes (when I sort by `votes`).

Should the accepted answer not always be listed on top no matter what sorting (`active`, `oldest`, `votes`) I choose?

Comment: Accepted answer by OP is treated as a normal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepting own answer is treated as a normal answer while sorting. So if the unaccepted answers has more votes then accepted one, it will be listed on top (when sorting by votes.)

Comment: In this case, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17401847, unaccepted answer has more votes than accepted one, but it comes at last (when sorting by votes).

Comment: @amitjha : The above rule applies only when OP himself answers the question and accept. In the question you have linked OP didn't answer himself.

Comment: IMO, this rule does not make sense. The answer marked as solution by the asker should be pinned to top, no matter who submitted it. The asker knows best. I've seen many cases where the answer marked as solution IS the correct solution. Voting for an answer is often simply a casual "i like this", not "i believe this is the solution".